# Show Cart Symbol next to Menu Toggle?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, cart

i have one small issue that dont know how to resolve myself. I use plugin to show custom cart symbol with dropdown effect. Now i want to integrate into my theme. Plugin offer shortcode. I tryed to put shortcode using php in this way:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[nwadcart_widget]"); ?>
```

but seems that is showing under on inside menu toggle. I want to show next to toggle like image bellow:

[image]

This is code from my theme Remix, from header.php

```
<div class="menu-toggle">

            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 18 18" enable-background="new 0 0 18 18" xml:space="preserve">

                <rect y="3" width="18" height="2"  class="svgfill"></rect>

                <rect y="8" width="18" height="2"  class="svgfill"></rect>

                <rect y="13" width="18" height="2"  class="svgfill"></rect>

            </svg>

        </div>
```

also i noticed that there is possibility to show social icons on that place. This is code where that social icons are shown, so may can put shortcode there.

```
<ul class="social-networks">

<?php foreach($iron_croma_social_icons as $icon): ?>

    <li>

        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url($icon["social_media_url"]); ?>">

             <?php if(!empty($icon["social_media_icon_url"])): ?> 

                /*<img src="<?php echo esc_url($icon["social_media_icon_url"]); ?>" style="max-height:50px;">*/
                <?php echo do_shortcode("[nwadcart_widget]"); ?>

            <?php else: ?>

                <i class="fa fa-<?php echo esc_attr($icon["social_media_icon_class"]); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($icon["social_media_name"]); ?>"></i>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </a>

    </li>



<?php endforeach; ?>    



</ul>
```

My site [URL](http://deil.cz/producer-page/) if someone need to see it.

Comment: Which plugin do you use?

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-ajax-drop-down-cart/5048421

Answer (score 0):

**If You want add by css then this will be helpfull**

```
a.wpmenucart-contents {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 20px !important;
    right: 70px !important;
}
```